# after recreate edmx no suitable method found to override

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

I delete `edmx` and create `new edmx` but I have two error!

Help me please!

Comment: You should provide the piece of code in question so we can help.

Comment: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // call base (autogenerated):
            this.OnModelCreatingBase(modelBuilder);

            // extend:            
            var workingShift = modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeWorkingShift>();
            workingShift.Property(e => e.LeaveDayHours).HasPrecision(16, 8);

Comment: // Additional dispose operations here.
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }